# how can I get system proxy setting in node js

Tags: node.js, proxy, electron

I'm writing a desktop application on windows with electron. Now I need to use the System global proxy setting as my own proxy while using request to get some data like this

```
    request({
        url: "http://ahdas.drnh.gov.tw/index.php",
        method: "POST",
        proxy: this.proxyRequestUrl,
        headers: {
            "User-Agent": this.mainWindow.webContents.session.getUserAgent(),
            "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "Cookie": cookies
        },
        form: {'act': 'Display/built/' + bookKey + "/" + postPageKey}
    }, (err, response, body) => {

    });
```

So, how can I get the System global proxy settings and assign that to this.proxyRequestUrl?

Comment: You could try using the [Electron net API](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/net/) which respects system proxy settings.

Comment: Hi,
@zzm did you find any solution ? i have the same issue :'(

Comment: @MarwenLandoulsi I followed Jastin's suggest and use Electron net API instead

Comment: I am the author of [os-proxy](https://github.com/sholladay/os-proxy), which does exactly what you are asking for. Though it doesn't yet support Windows, would love some help on that.

Answer (score 2):

If you make http calls from the renderer it will use the systems default proxy settings.

If you need to make http calls from the main process you could use [electron-remote remote-ajax-module](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-remote#the-remote-ajax-module) which will make the calls through a renderer process.

You can also use [`electron-fetch`](https://npmjs.com/package/electron-fetch) in the main process and it'll use the system proxy settings.

Comment: I mis-understood this comment to mean the http module. But experimentation shows electron does not set the proxy on the http module :(.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get-proxy-settings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-proxy-settings) package from NPM.

For details, refer to the [README](https://github.com/Azure/get-proxy-settings/blob/master/Readme.md) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61454688/4536543)