# How to get the current System Proxy in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, proxy

I am making a node application and already know how i can implement a Proxy if required, but i'm not sure how i actually check the current system proxy settings.

From what i read its supposed to be in `process.env.http_proxy` but that is undefined after setting a proxy in my windows proxy settings.

How does one get the current Proxy settings in NodeJS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get-proxy-settings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-proxy-settings) package from NPM.

It is capable of:

> Retrieving the settings from the internet settings on Windows in the registry

I just tested it on Windows 10 and it was able to get my proxy settings.

Alternatively, you can take a look at their [source](https://github.com/Azure/get-proxy-settings) and do this on your own. Here are some key functions:

```
async function getProxyWindows(): Promise<ProxySettings> {
    // HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
    const values = await openKey(Hive.HKCU, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings");
    const proxy = values["ProxyServer"];
    const enable = values["ProxyEnable"];
    const enableValue = Number(enable && enable.value);
    if (enableValue > 0 && proxy) {
        return parseWindowsProxySetting(proxy.value);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

function parseWindowsProxySetting(proxySetting: string): ProxySettings {
    if (!proxySetting) { return null; }
    if (isValidUrl(proxySetting)) {
        const setting = new ProxySetting(proxySetting);
        return {
            http: setting,
            https: setting,
        };
    }
    const settings = proxySetting.split(";").map(x => x.split("=", 2));
    const result = {};
    for (const [key, value] of settings) {
        if (value) {
            result[key] = new ProxySetting(value);
        }
    }

    return processResults(result);
}

async function openKey(hive: string, key: string): Promise<RegKeyValues> {
    const keyPath = `${hive}\\${key}`;
    const { stdout } = await execAsync(`${getRegPath()} query "${keyPath}"`);
    const values = parseOutput(stdout);
    return values;
}

function getRegPath() {
    if (process.platform === "win32" && process.env.windir) {
        return path.join(process.env.windir as string, "system32", "reg.exe");
    } else {
        return "REG";
    }
}
```